# Semi-definite Programming with Quadratic Objective

Tags: convex-optimization, semidefinite-programming

I was going through Stephen Boyd and lieven vandenberghe's Convex Optimization Book, In chapter 4 he explains Semidefinite programming (SDP) and it's the standard form.

min $c^{T}x$

subject to  $x_{1}F_{1} + x_{2}F_{2} +... + x_{n}F_{n} + G <= 0$

I was wondering as SDP is the superset to Quadratic Programming having quadratic objectives should be allowed right?

Comment: No, a quadratic term in the objective function does not fit the definition of an SDP. However, if you were to include a quadratic term in the objective function, there are tricks that would allow you to reformulate the resulting problem as an SDP.

Comment: Ok, so you mean that if I use epigraph trick I will able to reformulate it as SDP?

Comment: That book has **two** authors.

Comment: What if the quadratic objective becomes a non-convex inequality?

Comment: Yes, my bad, I have added the other author and as far as your second question goes I'm not sure what you mean by non-convex inequality, can you elaborate, please.

Comment: @littleO Hey, I am facing now the same problem and I just read that you can reformulate a quadratic objective function as an SDP. Can you provide some reference, please?

Answer (score 0):

In general, semidefinite programming uses dot product of vectors. The SDP can be written as follows:

$$
\begin{array}{rl}
\min_{(x_i)_{i=1}^{n} \in \mathbb{R}^n} & \sum_{j=1}^{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} c_{i,j} \langle x_i, x_j\rangle \\
\text{subject to} & \sum_{j=1}^{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{i,j,k} \langle x^i , x^j\rangle \leq b_k, \quad \forall k \\
\end{array}
$$

Comment: Thanks for the clarification

Comment: I don't see that this is equivalent to an SDP. Could you elaborate on that or provide a reference? How are semidefinite cone constraints handled in this formulation?

Comment: I know sdp from integer programming and maxcut. The main idea is $Y=[x_i.x_j]$. Check this report as a reference: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-251j-introduction-to-mathematical-programming-fall-2009/readings/MIT6_251JF09_SDP.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjf_8zZq7nmAhVPD7kGHaLnAHEQFjAFegQIBRAB&usg=AOvVaw0hazUeQA0waFYBJpJee9Qc

Comment: The optimization problem you've written isn't the same as the SDP which is on page 5 or the dual SDP which is on page 8 of that document. So I still don't see that what you've written is equivalent to a standard SDP. (And you seem to have no semidefinite cone constraint in your formulation.)

Comment: It is the same problem. The matrix $X=\langle x_i , x_j \rangle$ is a gram matrix. Thus $X$ is positive semidefinite. This problem is basically $\min \langle C,X\rangle$ subject to $\langle A_k,X\rangle , \quad \forall k$. Can you check this? I think that the problem written as in the answer above is more clear.        https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix

Comment: Sorry $X=[\langle x_i , x_j \rangle]$

Comment: For matrices $ A, B$, $$\langle A,B \rangle = TR(A^T B)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n} A_{ij}B_{ij}$$